# Royal "we" meaning?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, third-person, first-conditional

I heard the royals used 'we' instead of 'I'.

> The royals makes impressed food.
> So we are gonna roll out the red carpet and spare no expense.

Word 'We' means 'I' in this sentence?

Comment: Where is the sample sentence from?

Comment: Ignoring the first sentence as having no meaning, the *we are gonna roll out* is the normal plural we, not the royal we substituting for *I*. And whoever's gonna roll it out, it's not the royals.

Comment: In so far as this question is about royal *we* generally, it is answerable by consulting readily available reference sources. In so far as it is about the specific example, answering it is not going to provide any worthwhile insight into English language and usage, as the example is highly idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard the royals used 'we' instead of 'I'.

Not always. It is in **appropriate contexts only**

> The royals makes impressed food. So we are gonna roll out the red carpet and spare no expense.

This is the most unlikely example I could think of. Not only is the first sentence incomprehensible, the second is completely out of character - have you ever heard a monarch speak? Seriously?

A monarch uses "we" when addressing an audience and speaking of his official intentions. Otherwise, they use "I".

The use of "we" goes back to early Old English and means "we".

OED **We** Pron.

> **2. Used by a single person to denote himself or herself.**
>
> **a. Used by a sovereign or ruler. Frequently defined by the name or title added.**
>
> *The apparent Old English instances of this use are uncertain, and may
> rather show an inclusive plural use of the pronoun; see further B.
> Mitchell Old Eng. Syntax (1985) §252.*
>
> OE   Ælfric Catholic Homilies: 1st Ser. (Royal) (1997) xxix. 420
> *Witodlice we beorgað þinre ylde, gehyrsuma urum bebodum & geoffra þam
> undeadlicum godum.*
>
> 1854   W. M. Thackeray Rose & Ring xv   *[The herald]..began to
> read:—‘O Yes!..know all men by these presents, that we, Giglio, King
> of Paflagonia’ [etc.].*

The suggestion made by Mitchell above is reasonable and it is that the monarch speaks for himself and all his subjects.

This meaning seems closely related to

> **b. Used by a speaker or writer, in order to secure an impersonal style
> and tone, or to avoid the obtrusive repetition of ‘I’.**
>
> *N.E.D. (1926) states: ‘Regularly so used in editorial and unsigned
> articles in newspapers and other periodicals, where the writer is
> understood to be supported in his opinions and statements by the
> editorial staff collectively.’ This practice has become less usual
> during the 20th cent. and is limited to self-conscious and humorous*
> contexts.
>
> eOE   tr. Orosius Hist. (BL Add.) (1980) i. i. 12   *Nu hæbbe we
> scortlice gesæd ymbe Asia londgemæro.*
>
> 1965   S. Lipschutz Outl. Theory & Probl. Gen. Topol. iv. 47   *We
> assume the reader is familiar with the geometric representation of R
> by means of the points on a straight line.*

Comment: The subject of much humour in the UK, but in fact was only ever used when speaking in an official capacity. Queen Victoria's famous "We are not amused", **if** she ever said it, probably meant "we ladies", speaking of an off-colour joke.

Answer (score -2):

It is called

***[pluralis maiestatis](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/pluralis-maiestatis#:%7E:text=%5Bplu%CB%88ralis%20maies%CB%88tatis%20%5D,pluralis%20maiestatis%20the%20royal%20%E2%80%9Cwe%E2%80%9D)***

> pluralis maiestatis ***the royal “we”***

(Collins Dictionary)

> The royal we, majestic plural (pluralis majestatis), or royal plural, is the use of a plural pronoun (or corresponding plural-inflected verb forms) used by a single person who is a monarch or holds a high office to refer to themselves.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Does the answer connect with the sample sentence?

Comment: ....refer to themselves, which does not seem to be the case here.